# « Défenestrer », est-il un mot courant ?

Tags: usage

Si je comprends bien « défenestrer » veut dire « jeter par la fenêtre », mais est-il utilisé souvent ? Puis-je dire une phrase comme ceci :

> Mon ordi a planté et j’ai eu envie de le défenestrer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Oui, c'est un mot courant dans le sens où à peu près tout le monde sait ce que ça veut dire. Il est plus utilisé dans les journaux que dans des conversations, mais ça reste du langage courant.

Par contre attention, c'est un terme qui s'applique à une personne. Tu pourrais dire « défenestrer mon ordi » figurativement comme tu parlerais de le tuer, mais ça reste marginal.

C'est souvent utilisé pour parler de suicides ou d'homicides, parce qu'en général quand on passe par la fenêtre, on meurt...

EDIT : si tu veux le voir utilisé, tu peux taper « défenestré » sur google, et aller dans « Actualités ».

Comment: « Tout le monde sait ce que ça veut dire » me paraît assez utopique.

Comment: Sans doute utopique dans un monde parfait, mais tout le monde devrait sans doute le connaître avec un minimum de vocabulaire, ce n'est pas un mot savant. Ensuite, ça dépend du niveau d'éducation. C'est le seul mot qu'on a à disposition pour dire "jeter par la fenêtre", et il est tellement repris dans la presse...

Answer (score 3):

Sans qu'il s'agisse d'un mot usuel, il me semble que son côté sesquipédalien le rend de plus en plus populaire. Cela dit, le [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=d%C3%A9fenestrer%2Cjeter%20par%20la%20fen%C3%AAtre%2Cpr%C3%A9cipiter%20par%20la%20fen%C3%AAtre&year_start=1800&year_end=2016&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cd%C3%A9fenestrer%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cjeter%20par%20la%20fen%C3%AAtre%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpr%C3%A9cipiter%20par%20la%20fen%C3%AAtre%3B%2Cc0) le laisse marginal par rapport à *jeter par la fenêtre*

[image: Ngram *défenestrer* vs *jeter par la fenêtre* vs *précipiter par la fenêtre*]

Ne soyons donc pas [vésicolanternomane](http://www.cledut.net/xylo.htm) : il ne s'agit pas d'un mot courant.

Comment: Je comprends le langage courant comme quelque chose d'absolu : un mot fait partie du langage courant ou non. Et c'est pas parce qu'un synonyme est utilisé 4 fois plus que le mot ne fait pas partie du langage courant. Pour moi si tu peux utiliser un mot sans que personne te regarde bizarrement c'est du langage courant. Par exemple, « sesquipédalien » c'est pas du langage courant, mais « quinquennat » si, même si on l'utilise que dans un milieu spécifique ou à une certaine période.

Comment: D'ailleurs « sesquipédalien » n'est pas reconnu par mon correcteur orthographique ^^ Je sais que tu as fait exprès d'utiliser des mots peu courants, mais ça me fait marrer quand même. Et j'aime beaucoup ton lien !

Comment: @TeleportingGoat Dans ce cas, qu'attends-tu comme réponse ? Quel critère attends-tu pour déterminer si c'est un mot courant ou non ?

Comment: Je crois que j'ai répondu 2 fois à cette questio... En commentaire et dans ma réponse à Neil. J'ai dit "absolu" pour dire qu'on parle d'être dans le langage courant et non d'être courant ou non (soit fréquemment utilisé). Pour moi les deux choses sont différentes, le langage courant c'est un registre, un mot peut être dans le langage courant et utilisé une fois par an. Donc mon critère (c'est mon avis personnel) c'est si la grande majorité des gens connaissent le mot et qu'on peut l'utiliser sans se demander si les gens vont comprendre, je me trompe peut être !

Comment: Moi ça me choquerait pas d'utiliser le mot dans une conversation informelle : "Qui ça ?" "Mon voisin, il s'est défenestré la semaine dernière."